# Exporting Thunderbird from Win7 32bit to Win7 64bit

Tags: email, thunderbird, export, import, data-transfer

I am trying to export my thunderbird mails and mail accounts from my old win7 32bit to a new win7 64 bit.

Both have the same version (16.0.1). Earlier in this situation I just copy the Thunderbird folder found under my user data account (tried both local and roaming), but this is not working in this scenario.

I also tried to use Thunderbird export/import function, but it gives me a blank screen. This is what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: What happened when you first tried using the export mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of exporting and importing, you could copy all your mail data and [profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Windows_Vista_and_7) across. After copying, open `%AppData%\Roaming\Thunderbird\profiles.ini` in Notepad and update the `Path` to the directory where your profile is and ensure that `Default` is set to 1. If you don't have a profiles.ini file, run Thunderbird to create a new profile (you won't be using this profile later and can delete it).

Your profiles.ini should look like this:

> [General]
>   StartWithLastProfile=1
>
> [Profile0]
>   Name=default
>   IsRelative=0
>   Path=(Give The Complete Path To Your Profile Here)
>   Default=1

Comment: Thanks, Ive tried that (as I tried to explain in my question), but it is like Thunderbird does not recognize this - I still have empty thunderbird

Comment: Open the command prompt and launch the Profile Manager (using `Thunderbird -p` - if necessary go to the directory where Thunderbird is installed). In the Profile Manager, choose to create a new profile and note the directory where it creates it. Copy your old mail data into that directory and ensure that this profile is the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved it - still not sure why it was not working before